# How To Recognize Addiction To Gambling?

Tags: psychology

How to recongnize addiction to gambling? How to recognize when your bad plays are not due to tilt but addiction to gambling? What can be done?

Comment: Addiction to gambling is not in the same category as tilt. Bad plays stem from tilt, being tired, lacking key knowledge and sometimes just bluffing the wrong guy, to name a few. I don't see how you can make a link between the addiction and the quality of play.

Comment: Having said that, after re-reading I understand that you might mean making bad calls because you **want** to gamble, even if your cards are bad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you recognize when you are playing "on tilt"?](http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-do-you-recognize-when-you-are-playing-on-tilt)

Comment: off topic, poker is not gambling.

Comment: Whilst it is true that poker is not a pure game of chance like some others, the fact that there is a risk and reward element certainly makes it gambling and hence addictive.

Answer (score 2):

The gambler's anonymous site has a list of 20 questions as a starter.

Some things to note about addictions in general: It is not about the quantity but more about the emotions and behaviour.

The [CAGE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAGE_questionnaire) questions can also be applied (in part):

- Has the person ever tried to Cut down but couldn't?
- Has the person ever got Angry when questioned about their behaviour?
- Has the person ever felt Guilty about their behaviour?

As for what can be done - I believe Gambler's Anonymous follows the same 12 step program as alcoholics, drug addicts etc.

Although there are parallels between addictions, not all can be dealt with in the same way. For example, abstinence forms a key part in many recovery programs but for some addictions (over-eating, sex addiction etc), this isn't practical for obvious reasons.